# OpenCV webcam reconnect

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm using the OpenCV webcam example. Works great, but wondering, if it's possible to add a "camera reconnect function". When I unplug the camera, the code will crash. That's normal, but I would like to keep it running until I replug the camera again.

I tried "try: & except:" as you can see below. Now the python doesn't crash & when I unplug the camera, it will start printing "disconnected" to the console. However, when I reconnect the camera back, it would not start automatically, need to reset the program.

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)


#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
if cap.isOpened():
    while(True):
        try:
            # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, im= cap.read()

            # Display the resulting frame
            cv2.imshow('frame', im)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        except:
            print('Disconnected')
else:
    print("camera open failed")

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) means one camera

Comment: I know, I have an internal laptop camera (0) and an external USB cam (2). That's why in my code I'm using (2), so I can unplug it.

Comment: Does it also crash if you check whether read image isnt empfy and dont try to imshow it?

Comment: And if ret is false,can you try to .open the canera again?